# Why does my automatic RPG inventory grid not work?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

Here is my situation. I have four classes: Inventory.cs, InventoryTab.cs, ItemDatabase.cs, BaseItem.cs (and a few items that derive from BaseItem such as Weapon, Consumable, etc)

Inventory creates new InventoryTabs (Consumable, Weapon, Armor), and in each InventoryTab there is a list of BaseItems.

`Inventory.AddItemByID(int ID, int Amount)` is then called, which checks the IDs of ItemDatabase.cs, and has items pre-loaded into a list when the game is started.

Ok, now that you have basic info on how my inventory runs, here my problem:

In the InventoryTab:

```
int Column, Row; //Declared at the top of the class

for (int i = 0; i < ItemList.Count; i++)
{
    Column++;
    if (Column > gridSize.X)
    {
        Column = 0; Row++; //Row is not limited because my inventory will be unlimited in height
    }

    ItemList[i].gridLocation = new Point(column, row);
}
```

While I thought this would work, instead it creates one item at the top, and rapidly skips to the right, and then skips down one row, and repeats. If I add more items via a KeyboardState, it flashes a huge list of items, then disappears.

I'm certain it's because it is assigning the value of gridLocation in a loop, but then again I have no idea how I would go about it any other way.

What I need it to do is assign the gridLocation per BaseItem in ItemList only once.

EDIT:

InventoryTab.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace InventoryEngine
{
    public class InventoryTab
    {
        public List<BaseItem> ItemList = new List<BaseItem>();

        int itemSize; //In Pixels
        Point gridSize = new Point(5, 4);
        int LocY, Column, Row;
        public float Scale;

        //Region Clipping
        Rectangle scissorRect;
        RasterizerState rState = new RasterizerState()
        {
            ScissorTestEnable = true
        };

        Vector2 gridOffset;

        Texture2D slot;
        SpriteFont sf;

        MouseState ms;

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager c, GraphicsDevice g)
        {
            ItemDatabase.LoadItemData(c);

            slot = c.Load<Texture2D>("inventory_slot");
            sf = c.Load<SpriteFont>("SpriteFont1");

            Scale = 4.0f;
            itemSize = 32 * (int)Scale;

            gridOffset = new Vector2(g.Viewport.Width / 2 - (itemSize * gridSize.X / 2), g.Viewport.Height / 2 - (itemSize * gridSize.Y / 2));
            LocY = g.Viewport.Height / 2;
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gt, GraphicsDevice g)
        {
            ms = Mouse.GetState();

            LocY += ms.ScrollWheelValue / 10;

            if (LocY >= g.Viewport.Height / 2 - 252)
                LocY = g.Viewport.Height / 2 - 252;

            for (int i = 0; i < ItemList.Count / 1; i++)
            {
                Column++;
                if (Column > gridSize.X)
                {
                    Column = 0; Row++;
                }

                ItemList[i].gridLocation = new Point(Column, Row);
            }

            foreach (BaseItem item in ItemList)
            {
                item.UpdateValues(gridSize, itemSize, gridOffset, LocY);
            }
        }

        public void DrawTab(SpriteBatch sb, GraphicsDevice g)
        {
            scissorRect = new Rectangle((int)gridOffset.X, g.Viewport.Height / 2 - 256, gridSize.X * itemSize, gridSize.Y * itemSize);

            sb.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, rState);
            //g.ScissorRectangle = scissorRect;

            foreach (BaseItem i in ItemList)
            {
                sb.Draw(slot, new Vector2(i.itemRect.X, i.itemRect.Y), new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, Scale, SpriteEffects.None, .95f);
                sb.Draw(i.Icon, new Vector2(i.itemRect.X, i.itemRect.Y), new Rectangle(0, 0, i.Icon.Width, i.Icon.Height), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, Scale, SpriteEffects.None, .95f);
                //if (i.currentAmount > 1)
                    sb.DrawString(sf, "" + i.currentAmount, new Vector2(i.itemRect.X, i.itemRect.Y), Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, Scale, SpriteEffects.None, .95f);
            }

            sb.End();
        }
    }
}
```

BaseItem.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

namespace InventoryEngine
{
    public class BaseItem
    {
        public Texture2D Icon;
        public string name;
        string description;
        public int id, currentAmount, maxAmount;

        public enum TabType { Consumable, Weapon, Armor, Ammo, Jewellery, Resources, Misc }
        public TabType tabType;

        public bool isSelected, isUsable;

        public Vector2 positionOffset;
        public Point gridLocation;
        public Rectangle itemRect;

        public BaseItem(Texture2D IconName, int ID, string Name, string Description, int MaxAmount, TabType TabType)
        {
            Icon = IconName;

            id = ID;

            name = Name;
            description = Description;

            maxAmount = MaxAmount;

            tabType = TabType;
        }

        public void UpdateValues(Point GridSize, int itemSize, Vector2 GridOffset, int OffsetY)
        {
            currentAmount = (int)MathHelper.Clamp(currentAmount, 0, maxAmount);

            itemRect = new Rectangle(gridLocation.X * itemSize + (int)GridOffset.X, gridLocation.Y * itemSize + OffsetY, itemSize, itemSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post all relevant code. That loop shows us next to nothing. Also you never initialize Column or Row in the above.

Comment: Oh, alright. I'll edit my post. Also, I never initialize these variables because the for loop does that.

Comment: They are initialized when the class is made. Not in the for loop. If you need a grid form like a 2 by 3 grid for the inventory then you need a for loop in a for loop. This way it will initialize them column and row at same time. Right now you are only making 1 row and multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Going with @deathismyfriend you could run a nested for loop going through each position:

```
int pos; //Declared at the top of the class

pos = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < gridsize.X; x++) // x represents column
{
    for (int y = 0; y < ItemList.Count / gridsize.X; y++) // y represents row
    {
        // In the above (ItemList.count / gridsize.X) = number of rows needed
        ItemList[pos].gridLocation = new Point(x, y);
        pos++;
    }
}
```

And that **SHOULD** do what you want it to.

Mona

Comment: Sorry that I haven't been able to reply sooner, internet has been weird. Okay, I tried what you said exactly, and it draws each item at the top left corner, as if nothing is being applied. If you want, I'll post my update method when I get back from work. Honestly though, it should work, seeing that the for loops you wrote is logically sound. Thanks for the help so far though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ShyyGuy My pleasure, feel free to contact me anytime for help. Though I am quite an amateur myself, I'd love to help. I'm also quite busy with work for the next week or so, but will try to sneak in a quick update or two ;)

Comment: Alright. ^_^ I looked at my update code, and it hasn't changed since I posted this (very bottom on the very last box of code).

Comment: Also, when you assign pos to 0, do you do that in the update method? I tried both at the top of the class, in Update(), initialize & assign in Update(), and initialize & assign at the top of the class, but it didn't really change anything.

Comment: so I re-tried the code again, and it is half working... When ItemList.Count / GridSize.X is done, it only adds a new row onto it when itemList.Count is equal to gridSize.X, meaning that it will only ever be a full row. The leftover items are placed at 0, 0 (literally the top left corner of screen, not the gridLocation). So the problem is that I can't have 2 rows and 3 columns; it needs to be divisible by gridSize.X in order to draw a row. I'd greatly appreciate it if you could help me with this. By the why, I tried + ItemList.Count % gridSize.X, and it results in pos out of range.

Comment: @ShyyGuy could you please post a screen shot of what this looks like?

Comment: here is the picture: https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t31.0-8/10338569_761415393898027_5596447539542330685_o.jpg

Comment: Yes, and I have tried testing it quite a bit with little success. Sorry mate, but I can't find any problem. I recommend you debug it by adding `Console.WriteLine("Drawing item at pos {0}, {1}", x, y);` to try finding the error. Soz again.